# creating an object and initializing an object - Difference

Tags: javascript

```
  ////Creating Object
    var Obj;

  // init Object
  Obj= {};
```

1. What's the difference between these
   two?
2. Is it possible to make it into a
   single line?
3. Any Advantages of using like this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the first declares a variable in the current scope, it does not assign any value to it,thus it is not creating any object, while the second one creates an empty object literal to which you can refer through the global `Obj` variable.
There are 2 main differences : scoping variables and initializing vs declaring.
ex :

```
var Obj;
alert(typeof Obj);//='undefined'

//scoping : 
function foo(){
    obj1 = {};
    var obj2 = {};
}
alert(typeof obj1);//='object'
alert(typeof obj2);//='undefined'
// obj2 is visible only in the foo function scope,while
// obj1 is being attached to the global scope, the window object
// you can access obj1 as window.obj1 too
```

Answer (score 6):

`var Obj;` is **not** creating an object, it is **declaring** the *variable* `Obj`.

`Obj = {};` is **initializing** the variable `Obj` with an empty object.

Of course you can combine it and do it in one go:

```
var Obj = {};
```

You basically just have to separate declaration and initialization, if you want to initialize the variable with different values, based on some condition or if the variable should be declared in another scope. For example:

```
var Obj;

if(something) {
    Obj = 'me';
else {
    Obj = 'you';
}
```

Comment: @theJava: Still the same, only the name changed ;)

Answer (score 2):

`var Obj;` does **not** create an object, it **declares** a variable.

`Obj = {};` assigns an empty object to the variable named `Obj`. If `Obj` was not previously declared, this implicitly declares the variable in the global scope, since the `var` keyword is missing (don't do this).

Answer (score 2):

```
var Obj;
```

only *declares* the `Obj` variable, whereas

```
var Obj = {};
```

declares and initializes the `Obj` variable as an empty object.

Make sure you understand the use of the `var` keyword here as well. It can be used in declaring and/or initializing variables. The difference between

```
Obj = {};
```

and

```
var Obj = {};
```

is that the `var`-less code initializes `Obj` in the global namespace (often considered a bad practice).

---

**tl;dr:** In most cases, it is best to initialize and declare at the same time in the local scope, using the `var` keyword:

```
var Obj = {};
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm not totally understanding your question, but...

```
var Obj= {};
```

Is totally fine.

Answer (score 1):

The first allocates the slot for the variable `Obj` but leaves it undefined. The second binds a newly created object to the name `Obj`.

You can do it in one line: `var Obj = {};`. Doing it in two steps has no real advantages, only risks.

Answer (score 1):

```
var Obj;
```

this is not creating an object. it defines a variable;

object is first created and than initialized so this are two key processes that are both necessary to have an object.

Answer (score 1):

This line does not actually create an object.  Rather it creates a variable (or a place that could hold an object if you put one in there).

```
var Obj;
```

This line, does create an object, and places it into the variable.

```
Obj = {};
```

This line "initializes" the object by creating a property and setting it to something.

```
Obj.Something = null;
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that by saying

> var Obj;

you are not *creating* the object, merely defining a (in scope of a function local) variable initially set to null

Other than that there's no difference whether you merge it into one statement or not.

Comment: Actually, the value is not `null` but `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

If that's all the code you've got, there is absolutely NO difference between this:

```
var Obj;
Obj = {};
```

and this:

```
var Obj = {};
```

IF that's all the code you've got, with nothing in between modifying the `Obj` variable.  In fact, I'd argue that the second way of doing it would be faster than the two lines above.

Comment: I see it there.  Yeah, you'd be totally fine combining them into one line, and I'd recommend doing so.

Comment: well, there is A BIG difference : the type of the variables. undefined vs object, not to mention the scope

Comment: @gion_13 I'd argue that you're incorrect, and definitely didn't deserve the downvote.  The two code snippets that I have above will behave exactly the same when used as-is with nothing in between, as I've specified in my answer.  I'm talking purely from an implementation perspective, not from what actually happens behind-the-scenes, as yes `Obj` is set to undefined for ONE LINE where nothing happens after it except it being set to `{}`.